# Send data to server with Volley Lib in Android

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I've developed a Application that i'm going to send data from the phone to the server by `Json`, to do this i use **`Volley`** Library in Android.
but i can not send data to the server!

my simple php code :

```
$name = $_GET["name"];
$j = array('name' =>$name);
echo json_encode($j);
```

my java code :

```
private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "http://my-site-name/sampleGET.php";

        StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d("result:", response);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("err", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                makeJsonObjectRequest();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name", "json");
                return params;
            }
        };
        mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
    }
```

It also got help from the link below : [Click to see link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948191/send-post-request-using-volley-and-receive-in-php)

But still could not use it and send data from mobile to server!!!
How can I do this?
Please give me correct and how to use it

Comment: could you elaborate some more? what is the response that you do receive? this could be solved in more than one way depending on the response..

Answer (score 0):

I did a gist on this a while back I hope it can help.
You won't me uploading images, however you will be sending an example of which you can see on this line:

```
entityBuilder.addTextBody("someparameter", params.toString());
```

In the gist I use apache httpclient 4 with Volley. Link to the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/alphamu/7190a8ed0986b5fb8376).

Comment: tnx, but i want send data with POST of GET methods in Volley Library. can you help me?

Comment: That code does use POST. With GET you can just append everything in the URL as long as its not very long and is text.