# Error: "Method getText() must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker."

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

While working on the project i get an error on following Activity.
1. Login.java
on following Line of code.

Line:  "String username = user.getText().toString();"
Error: "Method getText() must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker."

This is my whole Activity Code.

```
package com.example.mysqltest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //php login script location:

    //localhost :
    //testing on your device
    //put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
    //or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
    // private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/login.php";



    //testing from a real server:
    //private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.example.com/webservice/login.php";

    //JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    public static String username;
    public static String password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        //setup input fields
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        //setup buttons
        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

        //register listeners
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.login:
                username = user.getText().toString();
                password = pass.getText().toString();
                new AttemptLogin().execute();
                break;
            case R.id.register:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;

            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComments.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: did you checked my answer ?

Comment: Yes i checked, it works. But some other errors come out. I have make another question for it and post it on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Sound's good, then accept my answer and post all your problems in a new question. i will try to resolve those as well :)

Comment: My reputation is low to accept as answer.

Comment: If you have less reputation also you can accept your own answer. you can find a tick mark below the up vote/down vote bar..simply check it !

Comment: Do you help in creating a android login php/mysql webservice using volley library?

Comment: Sure i vll.. But you can give a try and if you fail then post a question... refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046259/send-data-to-server-with-volley-lib-in-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless something has changed that I'm not aware of, that shouldn't be a problem. UI elements can't be updated from the background but accessing their getters has never been an issue.

Anyway, you can get around this by adding a constructor to your AsyncTask which would take the two Strings then send them when creating your task.

```
private class Login extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

// member variables of the task class
String uName, pwd
public AttemptLogin(String userName, String password) {
    uName = userName;
    pwd = password;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {...}
```

and pass them in your onClick()

```
case R.id.login:
 // execute method invokes doInBackground() where we open a Http URL connection using the given Servlet URL
 //and get output response from InputStream and return it.

 // pass them here

    new AttemptLogin(uname.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString()).execute();
                break;
```