# Volley POST Request receiving wrong results

Tags: android, api, rest, android-volley, postman

I have hosted my API on an online server. When I am testing it using the Postman app for chrome , its returning me the right results (ie. the details of the user from the database) But the below Volley request is getting wrong results (ie. Required Parameters missing);

**Screenshot of Postman Request**

[image: Postman Test Screenshot]

**Volley Request**

```
private void loginUser(final String username, final String password){

        String URL_REGISTER = "http://www.h8pathak.orgfree.com/jobs/login.php";
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
        showDialog();


        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                hideDialog();
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    int result = jObj.getInt("result");


                    if(result==1){

                        session.setLogin(true);

                        JSONObject jObj2 = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, EmployerActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("username", jObj2.getString("username"));
                        i.putExtra("email", jObj2.getString("email"));
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, jObj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, jObj.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }

                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }){

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()  {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }
        };

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);

    }
```

The **PHP Code** to receive request params and return the appropriate response.

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))  {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

      //Get the details from the database and echo in a json response

}

else{

    $message = "Required parameters missing!";
    $response['result']=0;
    $response['message']=$message;

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

What could be the possible mistake?

Comment: Did you add the username and password to request as parameters ? And also instead of StringRequest you should use JSONObjectRequest for this response.

Comment: what is the result you receive??share your logcat

Comment: what are the other data you have passed in the postman apart from the url itself ?

Comment: Please provide a full description of the problem. What exactly is going wrong? Did you already read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948191/send-post-request-using-volley-and-receive-in-php)?

Comment: @Artjom I have added more details to the question.

Comment: @SaravInfern I have mentioned the results now.

Comment: have you disabled the volley cache? it is enabled by default

Comment: I tried your API with postman as displayed in the screenshot and I get always `{"result":0,"message":"Required parameters missing!"}`. Please provide all settings you used in postman for a successful request.

Comment: @Artjom I just used the form-data in the body section and passed the username and password keys along with their values as shown in the screenshot. I didn't use any other setting along with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something is wrong with your server configuration: `http://www.h8pathak...` is not responding as expected, but `http://h8pathak...` works. The latter is used in your postman example, use it in you Android code and it will work there too.

Answer (score 0):

WWW is the answer.  This must be a bug. It goes to the URL and runs it but does not POST.

http://www.example.com/myphpfile.php is wrong.

http://example.com/myphpfile.php is right.