# Sent POST request but server says GET request in Android volley, what I am doing wrong here?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

### Java

```
 dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
 }
```

Here it is a simple volley request by which I want to send some post data, but it looks like request goes as a GET request

```
package xyz.hydroid.volleytest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  makeRequest();
 }

 private void makeRequest() {
  String url = "http://someurl/postin";

  StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
   new Response.Listener < String > () {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
     Log.v("Response", response);
    }
   },
   new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
     error.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  ) {
   @Override
   protected Map < String, String > getParams() {
    Map < String, String > params = new HashMap < > ();
    params.put("name", "Frostbite");
    return params;
   }
  };

  Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(postRequest);
 }

}
```

### PHP

Normally This php code returns server request 'POST' while testing on postman but not seems to be working with volley.

```
<?php 

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948191/send-post-request-using-volley-and-receive-in-php ,refer this

Comment: Thanks for your response. I followed the reference but couldn't solve the problem :( I still get server request method is GET. But I need POST.

Comment: everything seems correct ! I hope you set host , userId,password for your database at php script before echo REQUEST_METHOD

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I never thought of that kind of error :p.

I was requesting http://example.com/directory 
That causing the problem

When made request on http://example.com/directory/index.php , problem solved