# Using volley library, cant execute a post method form with parameters

Tags: android, android-volley, remote-server

I am working on volley library: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Get and 'Post methods without parameters' working fine. But when parameters are given, volley does not execute the form, and acts like form itself is a jsonObject:

> com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value Login< of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

I have tried both overriding getParams() method:

```
@Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }
```

And instantiating the object with parameter:

```
Map<String, String> params2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params2.put("username", username);
    params2.put("password", password);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest1 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL, new JSONObject(params2), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //onResponse
        }
    });
```

None of them worked. I am guessing my problem is about the content types. Volley library uses application/json while my php codes use name-value pairs.

I have seen these two questions but sadly they did not solve my case:

[Google Volley ignores POST-Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760212/google-volley-ignores-post-parameter)

[Volley Post JsonObjectRequest ignoring parameters while using getHeader and getParams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570909/volley-post-jsonobjectrequest-ignoring-parameters-while-using-getheader-and-getp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `JsonObjectRequest`, you are saying that the content you are posting is a `JSON Object` and the response you expect back will also be a `JSONObject`. If neither of these are true, you need to build your own `Request<T>` and set the values you need.

The error you are seeing is because the response from the server is not a valid JSON response.

Comment: I did post JSON and expected JSON. So I should use StringRequest because my form accepts namevalue pairs?

Comment: Maybe. It depends on what `Content-Type` the server is expecting, and exactly what the response is going to be. You can override `getBodyContentType` to change the request `Content-Type` if you need to post it as, say `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of a JSON `Content-Type`

Comment: As JsonObjectRequest sending application/json by default. Overriding it may solve my problem. I'll give it a go. Thanks